# batch file read and store in a text file string

Tags: string, batch-file, cmd, find, findstr

So i have multiple files that when opened it looks something like this

```
 THis is header
 A|0003920449219349||||B|skej24ie422|
 F|ddawejaskld
```

My question is how can I store the string in the second line specifically 0003920449219349(or the number between |) to a seperate text file (>storehere.txt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=2,3 delims=|" %%a in (*.txt) do if "%%b" neq "" echo %%a>>storehere.txt
```

... assuming, the format is really, what your example is like.

Comment: Instead of `if "%%b" neq ""`, skip header using `"skip=1 tokens=2,3 delims=|"` as we can't assume that the 1st line does not contain `|`. Also be aware of lines like `X||||something` with _empty_ 2nd column however _non-empty_ 2nd token `%%b`.

Comment: This would output all 2nd cols, not only the 2nd line.

Comment: @JosefZ: your suggestion would also return `ddawejaskld` from line 3, which isn't wanted. And because of "also be aware...", I wrote `... assuming, the format is really, what your example is like.` With some knowledge of the real data, this can be significantly improved (eg. is it always the second line, is it always starting with `A|` ...)